# Parsing multiple strings with the same code

Tags: python, parsing

I am trying to print all tennis players within URL below. But split function only prints one player name although other player's name can be retrieved from following split function names1.split('">')[1].split('

```
import time
import urllib2
from urllib2 import urlopen
import datetime

def Tennis():
    try:
        australianOpen = urllib2.urlopen('http://www.ausopen.com/en_AU/players/profiles.html').read()

        names1 =australianOpen.split('</div><div id="section_A" class="sectionHeading"><div class="men">A</div><div class="women">A</div></div><div class="section"><div class="men">')[1].split('</a></div></div></div></div>')[0]

        for Eachnames in names1 :

            Eachnames = names1.split('">')[1].split('</a><a href="')[0]


            print Eachnames


    except Exception,e:
        print str(e)

Tennis()
```

Comment: Trying to parse HTML in this fashion is cumbersome and hacky. Use [`BeautifulSoup`](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/).

Comment: Indeed don't do it like this. It will bite you in the long run

Comment: what's the question here?

Comment: also you can use `lxml` module and `xapth` to get all `href` from `a` tags.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem has to do with the line `Eachnames = names1.split('">')[1].split('</a><a href="')[0]` , what you are doing here is splitting the string into a substring array, then with the [1] you are selecting the 1:st element. Since you are not modifying the variable `names1`after you found the first name you will select the same name over and over again. A simple modification is

```
import time
import urllib
import urllib.request
import datetime

def Tennis():
    try:
        australianOpen =     urllib.request.urlopen('http://www.ausopen.com/en_AU/players/profiles.html').read().decode('utf-8')

        names1 =australianOpen.split('</div><div id="section_A" class="sectionHeading"><div     class="men">A</div><div class="women">A</div></div><div class="section"><div class="men">')[1].split('</a></div></div></div></div>')[0]

    the_names = names1.split('">')
    for name in the_names:
       print (name.split('</a><a href="')) 

    except Exception:
        print ("Exception", sys.exc_info()[0])


Tennis()
```

But the printout will be wrong since your search criterias are all wrong (unless you want jibberish such as half URL adressen et.c.). A good and easy solution I think is to use regular expressions for this. 
A simple regexp to catch the name, given no special characters or so is

```
the_names = re.findall("\">([A-Za-z]*, [A-Za-z]*)", names1)
```

A somewhat simplified program using regexp is

```
import urllib.request
import re

def Tennis():
    try:
        australianOpen = urllib.request.urlopen('http://www.ausopen.com/en_AU/players/profiles.html').read().decode('utf-8')

        names1 =australianOpen.split('</div><div id="section_A" class="sectionHeading"><div class="men">A</div><div class="women">A</div></div><div class="section"><div class="men">')[1].split('</a></div></div></div></div>')[0]
    except Exception:
        print ("Exception")

    the_names = re.findall("\">([A-Za-z]*, [A-Za-z]*)", names1)
    for name in the_names:
        print (name) 

Tennis()
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

just add names1 = names1[names1.find(Eachnames)+len(Eachnames):]

```
def Tennis():
    try:
        australianOpen = urllib2.urlopen('http://www.ausopen.com/en_AU/players/profiles.html').read()

        #print australianOpen
        names1 =australianOpen.split('</div><div id="section_A" class="sectionHeading"><div class="men">A</div><div class="women">A</div></div><div class="section"><div class="men">')[1].split('</a></div></div></div></div>')[0]

        for Eachnames in names1 :

            Eachnames = names1.split('">')[1].split('</a><a href="')[0]
            names1 = names1[names1.find(Eachnames)+len(Eachnames):]
            if Eachnames.find('<')!= -1:
             Eachnames=Eachnames[:Eachnames.find('<')]


            print Eachnames


    except Exception,e:
        print str(e)

Tennis()
```